# How to get rid of space below graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of but I cannot get rid of the extra blue space below the graph that appears when you hit the submit button.

Anyone know what's causing it?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W6xD6/)

Here's the CSS of relevant items:

```
#cccontainer {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    background-color: #447bc7;
}

#costComparer {
    width: 300px;
    float: left; 
}

#costComparer input {
    width: 100px; 
}

#result {
    width: 450px;
    float:right;  
}


#chart_div{
    display: none; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}

.spacer {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
```

and the relevant html:

```
<body>
<div id="cccontainer">
        <form id="costComparer" name="pricesForm">
            <table>
                <!-- my table --> 
            </table>                
        </form>

        <div id="result"></div>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width:400px; height:250px;"></div>
        <div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your blue container is to high. set it to 474px;

```
cccontainer.animate({height: 474});
```

And here's a

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/W6xD6/2/)

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the animation. I need to pay more attention. Thank you!

Comment: @ByronS inspect element is your friend. I Noticed the inline height and it was a short way to animation from there